# Rietveld Refinement: Calculated Intensities far lower than observed for a small selection of miller indices

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, x-ray-diffraction

[image: Calculated vs observed intensities for miller planes]

I'm performing a Rietveld Refinement in excel of an I4/mcm material CeAlO3. The fit is very good for most peaks but on a few, I'm coming up very short on the intensities. Could this be due to a local instead of global minima and how would one remedy this situation?

Comment: In general, rather that referring to your particular case, the starting values can often determine the outcome, so finding a local minimum looks like what has happened. (a) Try fitting each using a random selection of starting points to see if that improves matters. (b) Use another fitting programme rather than Excel which is not really designed for this type of problem.

Comment: Without knowing the structure and the expected variance of peaks with refinement, it could well be either a numerical solution problem or a physics problem. While vaguely impressed that you got something to work in Excel, I'm also quite horrified since I don't trust Excel to fit a straight line much less something complex like diffraction intensities.

Comment: If future answers to your question don't resolve the problem to your satisfaction, you may attempt a structure solution and refinement with an other program dedicated to PXRD.  If the ones compiled by IUCr [here](https://www.iucr.org/resources/other-directories/software) don't fit your needs, give [Fox](http://fox.vincefn.net/) a chance ([a more recent review/tutorial](https://www.mdpi.com/2073-4352/7/10/322/htm), open access).

Comment: For peak fitting (esp. PXRD data) and a simultaneous display of experimentally recorded intensity (or the profile fitted) in function of $2\theta$, the open source program [Fityk](https://fityk.nieto.pl/) seems to be more suitable than Excel, too.  Consider using this program once up and including the point to simultaneous display of fitted intensity profile and variation (against the experimental intensity) and add this as clarifying detail to your question (a total view and some regions where the modeled profile fits the experiment less well).